# Get most recent IDENTITY entry from SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Yes, I still have a SQL Server 2000 box (I know, I know . . .). Can someone please remind me the most reliable/safe way to retrieve the latest IDENTITY entry from a newly inserted records from a particular table? I know how to do it in SQL Server 2008, etc, but I cant remember if its different from SQL Server 2000

Answer (score 5):

SCOPE_IDENTITY. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259185(v=sql.80).aspx Don't *EVER* use @@IDENTITY. It should never be used for any reason EVER. Using it will cause you to break out in a rash, your wife to divorce you, and Dr. Who to be cancelled.

See: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e2d3/4 Behold the Heart of Darkness! Behold the evil that is @@IDENTITY! Use @@IDENTITY and lose your own!

Comment: Oh.  That explains it...   : (